# Plotly: markers of scatter plot vanish when there are more than 20 points

Tags: python, numpy, plotly

This issue is driving me insane. For some reason, when I try to plot more than 20 points in a scatter plot using plotly, the markers disappear. I made a minimum reproducible example as follows:

```py
def plot(n):
    
    fig = go.Figure()
    
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=np.arange(n), 
                             y=np.arange(n), 
                             marker=dict(symbol='circle', color='Blue', size=6)
                            ))
    
    fig.show()
```

Here are the outputs (in a jupyter notebook) for some values of n:

[image: Output for n=10]

[image: Output for n=15]

[image: Output for n=19]

[image: Output for n=20]

[image]

As you can see, the markers disappear when I go from `n=19` to `n=20` onwards. O tried removing the definition of `marker` in `go.Scatter`, but it didn't help.

Anyone has any idea what the heck is happening here? There is absolutely no changes to the `plot` function between executions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't set the value of the `mode` argument in `go.Scatter()` then plotly will use the default settings to determine how to plot data, i.e. it will plot lines and markers for less than 20 points and lines otherwise. To change it, set `mode` to an appropriate value: `mode='markers'` to plot markers only or `mode='lines+markers'` to plot both lines and markers:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
def plot(n):
    
    fig = go.Figure()
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=np.arange(n), 
                             y=np.arange(n),
                             mode='lines+markers',
                             marker=dict(symbol='circle', color='Blue', size=6)
                            ))
    fig.show()
```

Comment: Oof such a simple fix. Thank you!

Comment: Interesting. Do you know what the default mode is? I couldn't find the optional parameters for mode. And thanks for this fix.